# Network connection from guest VM works only to Hyper-v host (Hyper-v host is in turn installed on ESXi)

Tags: vmware-esxi, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

A Hyper-v host (Windows server 2008 R2) is installed on Vmware ESXi 5.5. Another Windows server 2008 R2 is installed as a guest on Hyper-v. The problem is that the guest does not have access to the rest of the network accept for the host. The virtual switch has external type. In similar scenarios not involving nested virtualization with ESXi networking works without any issues. Is there anything to check on ESXi side?

Comment: Could you maybe provide more detail in your question? [This meta answer](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask) provides some good tips on what to include in your question to help you get answers.

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue, I got the answer that I needed with the question as it is - I really don't see what can be added to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that you need to enable (Accept) promiscuous mode on the ESXi virtual switch that's attached to your nested Hyper-V host (which is in turn attached to your Hyper-V virtual switch).